# Understanding the Definition of signum function

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Mirsky and I am having a hard time understanding the footnote regarding the definition of the $\epsilon$ symbol. The chapter defines sgn x as
$$ 
\textrm{sgn x}=
   \begin{cases}
        1&(x > 0)\\
        0&(x=0)\\
       -1&(x<0)\\
    \end{cases}
$$
The books then goes on to give two definitions:
$$
\epsilon(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=\textrm{sgn}\prod_{1\leq r<s\leq n}^{}{(\lambda_s-\lambda_r)}
$$
and
$$
\epsilon\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1,...\lambda_n\\ 
\mu_1,...\mu_n
\end{matrix}\right)=\epsilon(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)\cdot\epsilon(\mu_1,...\mu_n)
$$
where $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and $(\mu_1,...,\mu_n)$ are arrangements of the integers $(1,...,n)$. There is then a footnote that states that
$$
\epsilon(\lambda_{k_1},...,\lambda_{k_n})=\textrm{sgn}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}^{}{(\lambda_{k_j}-\lambda_{k_i})}
$$
$(k_1,...,k_n)$ is also an arrangement of $(1,...,n)$. I do not understand why the footnote follows from the definition. For example, if $(k_1,...k_n)$ is equal to $(5, 1, 4, 2, 3)$ and $j=2$ and $i=1$ then $k_j=1$ and $k_i=5$. The would mean $s=1$ and $r=5$ which would not be valid values of $s$ and $r$ because the definition of sgn states that $r<s$. Could I get some help understanding this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define an inversion of $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ as an ordered pair $(\lambda_r,\lambda_s)$ such that $r<s$ and $(\lambda_r>\lambda_s)$. Let $K$ be the number of inversions in $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n.)$ Then $$\epsilon (\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=(-1)^K$$ . So you are seeing whether the number of inversions in the arrangement is even or odd.